# Why is using "new" to create a Javascript array considered bad?

Tags: javascript, arrays

[W3 Schools says](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

> These two different statements both create a new array containing 6
>   numbers:

```
 var points = new Array(40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10)  // Bad 
 var points =[40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];          // Good
```

but doesn't give an explanation why the first is bad.

From what I understand, the only difference is that the first calls the constructor. Can someone clue me into why the first is bad?

Comment: Where did you read it's bad?

Comment: W3 schools has a lot of bad and downright wrong information. You should literally never go there.

Comment: W3Schools is indeed a bad resource, but it's right in this case.

Comment: W3S might be wrong in some places but it's success tells me something: Other projects should make their documentation more consistent and improve their usability. I'm well aware of its quirks but sometimes I just use the site because I immediately find what I'm looking for while other documentation pages are a pain to read compared to them.

Comment: other sites "are a pain to read" ... ??? Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) gives definitions that are clear, often with examples and secondary links for more informations. The time lost by having a wrong information (W3S has so much of them) make this commercial site just wrong. On the other side, googling "MDN the_thing_i_seek" provides perfect information as first link 99% of the time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The true reason is that this constructor is inconsistent.

```
var points = new Array(40)
```

creates an array of size `40` and no content while

```
var points = new Array(40, 50)
```

creates an array of size 2 with 2 elements.

It's just simpler and more readable to use

```
var points = [40];
```

or

```
var points = [40, 50];
```

There's also no reason to use this constructor when you want to build a array, just use a literal array, exactly like you're using literal numbers.

Only use the `Array` constructor when you want to build an empty array with a given size (which should be very rare).

**ES 2015 edit:**

Due to this inconsistency, ES2015 brought us a new static function, [`Array.of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of). `Array.of(40)` makes the `[40]` array.

Comment: You could mention that the array length can also be set after instantiating an empty array. For example `var a = []; a.length = 50;`.

Comment: Well... yes, but why would you write that ? I'd rather user `new Array(50)` in this specific case.

Comment: The first example I can think of, would be to make a `copy` of an existing array for a comparison. [Use case here](https://gist.github.com/soyuka/950371df21c0947535f3#file-concurrency-js-L11). It's also a way to have the same behavior as `new Array(length)`.